# Autocomplete for PHP Objects with classes in PDT/Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

When I define an object of a class using new like this

```
$blah = new Whatever();
```

I get autocomplete for $blah. **But how do I do it when I have $blah as a function parameter?** Without autocomplete I am incomplete.

**Edit**: **How do I do it if it's in an include and PDT or Netbeans can't figure it out?** Is there any way to declare types for variables in PHP?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Method in first comment is called "type hinting", but you should use that wisely. Better solution is phpDoc.

```
/**
 * Some description of function behaviour.
 *
 * @param Whatever $blah
 */
public function myFunction($blah)
{
    $blah-> 
    // Now $blah is Whatever object, autocompletion will work.
}
```

You can also use an inline phpDoc comment which does exactly the same thing.

```
public function myFunction($blah)
{
    /* @var $blah Whatever  */
    $blah-> 
    // Now $blah is Whatever object, autocompletion will work.
}
```

Comment: Alan, are you saying this works in PDT because in Netbeans class Joe {
    public $a;
    public $b;
}

/* @var $joe Joe */
$joe->
doesn't give you autocomplete.

Comment: I just tried this in Netbeans 6.9.1 and it works like a charm. In my opinion simpler than the accepted answer, seems that the php support has improved since Yar's comment was added.

Answer (score 8):

Try to pass parameter class definition into the function:

```
function myFunction(Whatever $blah) {
}
```

Comment: that works, but now I´ve expanded the question, hope you don't mind! Thanks for your great answer, that already helps.

Comment: Ah, and about "Edit": I really don't know how to make it in elegant way. But my Eclipse+PDT installation resolve class parameters in similar cases well.

Comment: Okay, if no one can beat that -- very possible, but maybe there's some commmenty way to do it -- I'll give you best answer. Try Netbeans, I just switched from PDT... you might dig it.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll definitely give Netbeans a try. To be fair - I didn't see the PHP in NB yet, just java and ruby.

Comment: Hmm.. just tried this in NetBeans 6.5 and it works. I've made a Sample class with some vars, place it in separate file, include this file in my script, create the $sample var using new() and pass this var in function with type definition. And I've got the autocomplete for this var within function...

Comment: And now I'm in doubt about my favourite PHP IDE :(

Comment: Ok, you've won - I'll make my next project in NetBeans :)
Also, take a look at this topic: http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=146248 - hope that they add something like /* @var variableName */ in NetBeans in future releases.

Comment: I'm doing my next project in Ruby, so we're even.

Comment: maxnk, check my new answer below now that you use Netbeans :)