# Declaring Variable Types in PHP?

Tags: php, variable-types

[I was trying to get my Netbeans to autocomplete with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390192), and I learned that this code is valid in PHP:

```
function blah(Bur $bur) {}
```

A couple of questions:

1. **Does this actually impose any limits** on what type of variable I can pass to the blah method?
2. If this is just to help the IDE, that's fine with me. **How can I declare the type of a variable in PHP if I'm not in a function?**

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This type-hinting only works for validating function arguments; you can't declare that a PHP variable must always be of a certain type. This means that in your example, $bur must be of type Bur when "blah" is called, but $bur could be reassigned to a non-Bur value inside the function.

Type-hinting only works for class or interface names; you can't declare that an argument must be an integer, for example.

One annoying aspect of PHP's type-hinting, which is different from Java's, is that NULL values aren't allowed. So if you want the option of passing NULL instead of an object, you must remove the type-hint and do something like this at the top of the function:

```
assert('$bur === NULL || $bur instanceof Bur');
```

**EDIT:** This last paragraph doesn't apply since PHP 5.1; you can now use NULL as a default value, even with a type hint.

**EDIT:** You can also install the [SPL Type Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php) extension, which gives you wrapper types for strings, ints, floats, booleans, and enums.

**EDIT:** You can also use "array" since PHP 5.1, and "callable" since PHP 5.4.

**EDIT:** You can also use "string", "int", "float" and "bool" since PHP 7.0.

**EDIT:** **As of PHP 7.4, you can declare member variables of a class/interface/trait as a specific type** like `public int $a;`, and variables that are declared this way cannot be assigned to a value of another type. You can also use [union types](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/union-types) such as `string|int` as of PHP 8.0, and you can use classes in the union types as of PHP 8.1.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php

Comment: Complete and great answer. I'll admit that my main focus was to get my IDE hinting, which I have already figured out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390192... personally, I find that many aspects of PHP are depressing hacks, but that's just my preference for typed langs.

Comment: There there, even those of us who don't prefer strongly-typed languages agree with you :)

Comment: A good step  for PHP would be the option to declare type or leave it to be dynamic. I hope to see that in future PHP

Comment: I slightly disagree or want to make more precise the first EDIT: null is never of valid type $myClass (PHP 5.3). Perhaps it works as default param, but one still can't pass it in (like in Java) if a type hint in function signature are used.

Comment: Actually you can declare `myFunc(MyClass $x = NULL)`, and then call `myFunc(NULL)` or `myFunc()` without an error.

Comment: Not allowing `null` for type hinted parameters by default is something that I really like. As you say, Java allows this and they are now screwing around with `@Nullable` and `@NotNull`. I think the PHP implementation helps a lot to prevent null reference errors.

Comment: PHP 7.2 adds `object` as well

Comment: Too bad you can't specify an array of objects e.g.: `functionName(int[] $someIds)` or `functionName(SomeObject[] $someObjects)`, but there is partial workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34273821/448816

Comment: For allowing null values, you can also do `function blah(?Bur $bur) {}` (note the `?` in front of `Bur`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38129401/4284627.

Answer (score 44):

1. Specifying a data type for a function parameter will cause PHP to throw a catchable fatal error if you pass a value which is not of that type.  Please note though, you can only specify types for classes, and not primitives such as strings or integers.
2. Most IDE's can infer a data type from a PHPDoc style comment if one is provided.  e.g.

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
public $variable = "Blah";
```

**UPDATE 2021:** As of PHP 7 (which is several years old at this point) primitive types can also be declared for function arguments.  Nullability can also be indicated with a ? in front of the type from 7.1 onward.  You can declare return types now too. So this is valid PHP these days:

```
public function hasFoo(?int $numFoos) :bool {
```

phpStorm (my current preferred IDE) is happy to use all of these types for code completion, so I don't need as many phpDoc comments for typing as I used to.

Comment: what if I'm not in a class? The $variable is coming from an included PHP... I think I'm almost where I need to be...

Comment: No need to test. According to the PHP docs "Failing to satisfy the type hint results in a catchable fatal error." http://ch2.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting

Comment: i confirm, it works perfectly with eclipse PDT, thanks for the "Most IDE's can infer... " mention.

Answer (score 9):

It's called type hinting, added with PHP 5. It isn't quite what you may be expecting if you are coming from a language like Java. It does cause an error to be thrown if you don't pass in the expected type. You can't type-hint primitives, though (no int $bur).

Answer (score 9):

#2 : (...) How can I declare the type of a variable in PHP if I'm not in a function?

I recently heard about "[settype()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)" and "[gettype()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)" in PHP4 & 5
You can force the variable type anytime easily

---

From PHP.net :

bool settype  ( mixed &$var  , string $type  )

Parameters

var : The variable being converted.
type : Possibles values of type are:

- "boolean" (or, since PHP 4.2.0, "bool")
- "integer" (or, since PHP 4.2.0, "int")
- "float" (only possible since PHP 4.2.0, for older versions use the deprecated variant "double")
- "string"
- "array"
- "object"
- "null" (since PHP 4.2.0)

[ :D First visit, first comment...]

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. settype and gettype are only for primitives, which doesn't help (although technically it does answer the question, so I'll vote you up. Please provide a link to the PHP doc and remove it from your answer).

Comment: `$myVar=(string) $variabel;`  gives a string Variable. Afterwards, assign a value.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this actually impose any limits on what type of variable I can pass to the blah method?

This is called [type hinting](http://ch2.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting). According to the PHP documentation that I just linked to, yes, it does impose limits on the argument type: "*Failing to satisfy the type hint results in a catchable fatal error.*"

> How can I declare the type of a variable in PHP if I'm not in a function?

Read [type juggling](http://ca.php.net/language.types.type-juggling). You can't explicitly define a variable's type in PHP, its type is decided by the context it is used in.

Comment: @Jeremy Ruten: actually the link to `type hinting` is broken.