# Is it possible to specify multiple return types on PHP 7?

Tags: php, php-7, type-hinting

I have some methods that can return **one of two return types**. I'm using a framework utilizing MCV so refactoring these few functions in particular is not appealing.

Is it possible to declare the return type returning one or the other and failing on anything else?

```
function test(): ?
{
    if ($this->condition === false) {
        return FailObject;
    }

    return SucceedObject;
}
```

Comment: Only if both `FailObject` and `SucceedObject` both share an interface or extend from a common parent

Answer (score 160, accepted):

As of PHP 8+, you may use [union types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2):

```
function test(): FailObject|SuccessObject {}
```

Another way, available in all versions since PHP 4, is for the two objects to share an interface. Example:

```
interface ReturnInterface {}
class FailObject implements ReturnInterface {}
class SuccessObject implements ReturnInterface {}
function test(): ReturnInterface {}
```

In this example, `ReturnInterface` is empty. Its mere presence supports the needed return type declaration.

You could also use a base, possibly abstract, class.

---

To me, for this use case, interfaces are more clear and more extensible than union types. For example, if I later want a `WarnObject` I need only to define it as extending `ReturnInterface` -- rather than going through all signatures and updating them to `FailObject|SuccessObject|WarnObject`.

Comment: Worth the upvote for your mention of the union types RFC

Comment: You could also use an `abstract class` here.

Comment: This is really limiting: think at entites (used, for example, by Doctrine): it is not possible to hint the return to `null|Entity`. Really limiting...

Comment: @Aerendir a solution/workaround for this would be having the repository method return an Option that wraps the null type or Entity. Here's an example of a package that provides an Option type: https://github.com/schmittjoh/php-option

Comment: Has this RFC passed?

Comment: @tangobango As noted in the answer: no, the RFC was declined.

Comment: @Aerendir `null|Entity` is available in PHP 7.1 with nullable types: `?Entity`. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php.

Comment: PHP 8 will support union types https://helpdev.eu/php-8-0-vote-on-union-types-ended/

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to allow multiple return types of objects? Or even mixed parameter type hinting. Or even just different return type values at all? Robust and clean SRP/SoC code simply doesn't need this. If you find yourself needing it honestly rethink it, it's really likely to be unnecessary. `FailObject|SuccessObject` so I get potentially get two different objects back? Do I need to if/else to know which getters to use? This is bonkers. Just return true/false. Or a single object with a method `isSuccessful(): bool{}` and either way my result is there

Answer (score 84):

As noted by bishop, there is an RFC for adding multiple return types. However, I thought I'd add that as of PHP7.1 you can now specify a nullable return type like this:

```
function exampleFunction(string $input) : ?int
{
    // Do something
}
```

So this function would take in a string and by adding the question mark before int you are allowing it to return either null or an integer.

Here's a link to the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

And here's a quote from that page explaining the usage: 
PHP 7.1 allows for void and null return types by preceding the type declaration with a ? — (e.g. function canReturnNullorString(): ?string)

Also, here's another thread that relates to this:  [Nullable return types in PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608821/nullable-return-types-in-php7)

Comment: "allows for void and null return types by"  Returning null works for me, but void throws an exception.  "...or null, none returned ..."

Comment: If I use "return;" the error becomes: "A function with return type must return a value"

Answer (score 26):

PHP from 7.2 onward supports the object return type

http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.new-features.php

```
function test(object $obj) : object
// return any type of object ...
```

Answer (score 12):

Since PHP 8.0 [this is possible](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2).

You can now use union types to specify this:

```
function test(): Success|Failure
{
    if ($this->condition === false) {
        return new Failure();
    }

    return new Success();
}
```

The fact that this is possible **does not mean that it is always advisable**. In many (probably most) situations, using an interface (e.g. `Result`, which both `Failure` and `Failure` would implement) as advised in a different answer, is still much preferable.

But there are other instances where union types could make sense to an alternative to weak typing. E.g. a method that accepts both `string` and `int`, or to describe the return type of a function like [`stripos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), which returns `int|false`.

Answer (score -9):

**This ins't correct way:**

```
function test(): ?
{
    if ($this->condition === false) {
        return FailObject;
    }

    return SucceedObject;
}
```

**Multiple return type is a bad practice.** Good practices:

You should define a exception:

```
class FailObjectException extends \Exception
{
    private $exampleExtraInfo;

    public function __construct($exampleExtraInfo, $message)
    {
        parent::__construct($message);
        $this->exampleExtraInfo = $exampleExtraInfo;
    }

    public function exampleExtraInfo(): int
    {
        return $this->exampleExtraInfo;
    }
}
```

Now, you can define function like:

```
function test(): SucceedObject
{
    if ($this->condition === false) {
        throw new FailObjectException(...,...);
    }

    return SucceedObject;
}
```

And use this function with try/catch:

```
try{
    $succeedObject = $any->test();
} catch (FailObjectException $exception){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should *not* be used to control the flow of an application. You're essentially treating the Exception here as an if statement, which is not the correct usage of an exception.

Comment: are you saying that failure case isn't a exception? Mmm...

Better return a "FailObject" and control multiple outputs: if, elseif, elseif, else. (NO)

Comment: I'm suggesting the code is structured correctly so that you don't need to rely on either :)

Comment: It's necesaty set stric types to write clean, maintainable and robust code.

Descripted case (with 'FailObject') is a manual exception. It is not a exception to controll the flow. The flow continue with success case. You dont have to controll the exception before app controller.