# What type hint to use if return value is mixed?

Tags: php, return, php-7, type-hinting

```
function foo ($a): mixed
{
    if ($a == 1)    
        return true;
    else
        return 'foo';
}

var_dump(foo(1));
```

Since `mixed` is not a real type this results to:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of foo() must be an
>   instance of mixed...

Is there a way to type hint a `mixed` return value or do you simply not declare type hints in this type of scenario?

Comment: I think you just don't declare them.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033142/multiple-return-types-php-7 although I don't think I'd call it a duplicate.

Comment: FWIW, an RFC is up for consideration for inclusion in 7.4 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed-typehint

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Type hints are there to enforce some restriction on the value passed or returned. Since "mixed" would allow any value at all, its use as a type hint would be pointless, so just omit it.

From PHP 8.0 onwards, [you can specify "union types"](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#union-types), which would allow you to declare the return type in your example as `bool|string`. (There is also a special case for including `false` in the union, as in `false|string`, since it's commonly used to indicate failure, but not for `true`.)

As an alternative to `false|string` you can use [nullable type hints](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.nullable), which are available from PHP 7.1 onwards. , and can be specified as `?string` if you want to return `null` on a failure instead of `false`.

In older versions, you can *document* the return value of your function, in a docblock. IDEs and documentation generators will generally understand the syntax `@return bool|string`. Even if you are using PHP 8, you might want to use this to add a description of *why* the return type varies, and when to expect which type.

Of course, an option well worth considering is to reconsider your design, and come up with a function which can communicate its result *without* returning different types for different cases. For instance, using exceptions instead of a special value for errors, or splitting a function like `getThing(boolean $asString): float|string` into two functions `getThingAsFloat(): float` and `getThingAsString(): string`.

Comment: I think the "final" option should probably be the first option here. If yer method is possibly returning different types, it could be doing too much, or its design could be off in another way. Probably a good cue to have a look at the design again anyhow.

Comment: @AdamCameron there are many cases where mixed values are acceptable. Many PHP native functions returns mixed values (e.g., `mysqli_query()`)

Comment: I would not cite the native PHP functions that return mixed types as examples of good design though. The one you cite is a prime example of where PHP has historically been a mess: it should return a resultset (poss an empty one), or raise an exception. The boolean return value situations there are a rubbish way of dealing with the situation. I think you'll find other PHP functions that act similarly are also likely to be indicative of subpar design.

Comment: @AdamCameron What constitutes "good design" or "acceptable" will always be partly a subjective judgement, but in general, I agree with you. If you're taking the effort to think about return type hints to the point of writing a question like this, you can probably afford a bit of time to examine if avoiding them would make your API easier to use.

Comment: Def. Hence my liberal use of the words like "probably" and "possibly" in my initial comment. My comment was a cue to just check to verify the curent approach *is* correct, rather than saying it wasn't correct.