# Dealing with PHP fatal type errors caused by introduction of type hinting

Tags: php, phpstorm

**TL;DR**

- Can we configure PHP so that it will not cause fatal errors when a parameter is of a wrong type caused by type hinting, and cause warnings instead?
- Are there plugins / extensions for PhpStorm / GIT that prevent the saving or pushing of code that contains unresolved problems (preferably filtered for only problems with type hinting).

---

For a project with a somewhat funky code base I am working on we are trying to incorporate type hinting where we can.
We decided to do this to make the code base easier to read and maintain.

I come from a C# background, so obviously the compiler has made me lazy because it basically tells me when I am trying to pass a value of an incorrect type. In PHP, we must rely on the IDE telling us, but since there is no compiling, it really does not prevent us from implementing code paths that will result in fatal errors at runtime.

Since we both want to keep using these type hints, and not have it cause fatal errors on runtime, we were wondering whether or not it is possible to configure PHP in a way that it will throw a WARNING as opposed to a FATAL when type hinting fails. This would allow the code to keep running and still notify us of the fact that we need to fix this problem.

*I understand that type hints should cause fatals by design, however we are trying to work around this temporarily*

What would work for us as well (and would probably be ideal), is some sort of a plugin that somehow prevents us from saving / pushing code that has unresolved issues like this. We are using PhpStorm and GIT for versioning.

Comment: Have you considered adding automated unit tests that would catch these fatal errors during the development?

Comment: @EriksKlotins Yes a lot actually, however the code base I am working on is very big and starting to add testing is not a trivial matter unfortunately. If only it was.

Comment: It feels like you really want to set up a [static analysis tool](https://github.com/exakat/php-static-analysis-tools) and PhpStorm has a builtin "Strict type checking rules violation" inspection that should also warn you. I guess the key point is automating it, am I right?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think we already use this (I am not so comfortable with PHP yet, so I might be wrong). The thing is though that I want a tool to prevent the code to become merged with the main branch (and the strict type checking only warns). I don't care in which stage it is prevented, somewhere in PhpStorm or the Git client seemed logical to me.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to start implementing automated tests on any new code that is added, or old code being changed. Thus, you will immediately see if you have broken anything or there is an execution path that triggers type errors.

[Here is an article on how to implement test automation in legacy systems](https://www.sourceallies.com/2012/04/automated-testing-strategies-for-legacy-systems/)

Comment: I'm a proponent of automated testing and I would gladly add tests if it were at some level possible. I will reconsider based on the article you've provided. However, even if we had automated testing, it would not guarantee the absence of type errors caused by the addition of type hinting as humans still have to cover all these cases.

Comment: Assuming the system works as it is, tests are needed only for the changed parts. Sure, humans still are needed to design test cases. However, you do it once and never look back to the same issue again

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether or not this is possible, I would suspect it is.

However: please don't.

Instead you could:

- Write unit tests, for example [using PhpUnit](https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html)
- Allow "null" responses and parameters while requiring a type if value is passed
- Require code to pass certain conditions using code quality checkers, such as [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/) (there are many others!)

For the null response or null param, consider the following:

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bcc_user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $bcc;
```

This is an example of a property of a class in one of my projects. For a Mail Entity in this case. It's supposed to have a class object of instance User. A normal (generated) getter/setter would end up being:

```
/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getBcc() : User
{
    return $this->bcc;
}

/**
 * @param User $bcc
 *
 * @return Mail
 */
public function setBcc(User $bcc) : Mail
{
    $this->bcc = $bcc;

    return $this;
}
```

However, it's the "bcc" of an email. Soooo, it can be null. Or a value can be removed for it to be null. So, we must allow a `null` as param in the setter. The getter must be able to return `null`.

```
/**
 * @return null|User
 */
public function getBcc() : ? User
{
    return $this->bcc;
}

/**
 * @param null|User $bcc
 *
 * @return Mail
 */
public function setBcc( ? User $to) : Mail
{
    $this->bcc = $bcc;

    return $this;
}
```

Done. 2 question marks is all it took.

Also have a look at [this question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033142/multiple-return-types-php-7) and the [PHP 7.2 "new features"](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.new-features.php) release notes.

Comment: Allowing parameters to be null seems hacky to me, unless they "can" be null like in your example. Our problem is that our devs accidently pass null where they should check it or throw an exception or w/e. As I said in a different answer, unit tests seem great to me as I don't normally work without them, but it's kind of hard in this specific project. Codacy is something I will have to take a look at, if it prevents us to commit or save code that isn't valid according to Codacy that would definietly be something I would want to use.