# PHP type annotation, Collections and ArrayObject

Tags: php, json, types, collections, arrayobject

I want to create a data structure and serialize it to json, with empty lists and empty objects.
The code currently uses empty php arrays for both.

To generate an empty object {}, I tried to use an ArrayObject.
However, I am searching for a common type between array and ArrayObject, so that I could type annotate my functions without specifying whether it returns an array or an ArrayObject.

Ex :

```
public function getEmptyList() :CommonType {
    return [];
}

public function getEmptyObject() :CommonType {
    return new ArrayObject();
}
```

Note : for some obscure reason to me, ArrayObject does not implement Ds\Collection

Comment: You could create a class handling both and then use this as the object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple return types php 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033142/multiple-return-types-php-7)

Comment: `array` is a native scalar type, not an object.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I can fix this without modifying all the code. I discovered ArrayObject is not compatible with array_keys, array_values and other methods so I cannot use it directly to replace an array