# php type declaration union on return (object or bool)

Tags: php, type-declaration

I am writing my code with type declarations on the return value (php 7.3). When I return just one type this is not a problem (as in the example below, `DoSomething1` will return an object of `SomeOtherClass`). Quite often though I find the need to do validation and return a `false` if the operation fails. I know I cannot do union on the return (as per `DoSomething2`), but is there a decent workaround for this problem?

```
class SomeClass {

  // Works
  function DoSomething1 (array $withMe) : SomeOtherClass {
    return new SomeOtherClass();
  }

  // Problem, would like to return OR a SomeOtherClass OR a bool
  function DoSomething2 (array $withMe) : SomeOtherClass|bool {
    if (/* some validation code that will return false */)
      return false;  
    return new SomeOtherClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033142/is-it-possible-to-specify-multiple-return-types-on-php-7

Comment: Nick, yes that actually helps me a lot. Will update my answer with this information as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching i found the answer to my own question:

[Is it possible to type hint more than one type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775489/is-it-possible-to-type-hint-more-than-one-type)

Short version:

- This is not possible
- Will be possible in php8
- @return in documentation will support Union types

Also as @Nick pointed out, this is a quite elegant workaround that works for me:

```
class SomeClass {
  function DoSomething2 (array $withMe) : ?SomeOtherClass { // note the ?
    if (/* some validation code that will return false */) 
      return null;   // not false but null
    return new SomeOtherClass();
  }
}
```