# Symfony Doctrine get number of Entity fields that not null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I get number of fields in entity (without manually counting) and then get number of this fields that are not null? This is what've done so far. But I get exception if one of the field's value is actually `null`.

```
$accessor= PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
$userProperties = $em->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:User')->getFieldNames();

$allFields = count($userProperties);
$notNullFields = 0;
foreach ($userProperties as $userProperty){
        if($accessor->getValue($user, $userProperty)){
            $notNullFields +=1;
        }
    }
```

Error I get:

> Type error: Return value of AppBundle\Entity\User::getStatus() must be of the type string, null returned (500 Internal Server Error)

which makes sense, because `status` is null in db.

So how can I count fields that are not null? Are there better solutions? The problem is not that `getValue` is returning `null`, but how to ignore `null` values and count not null values

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: @kero `Type error: Return value of AppBundle\Entity\User::getStatus() must be of the type string, null returned (500 Internal Server Error)` - which makes sense. because `status` is null in db

Comment: Did you provide the return type? Something along the lines of `function getStatus(): string {`? If so, then this is the problem

Comment: yes, I did. so how this can be fixed?

Comment: If you're on PHP7 you can use `?string` as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608821/nullable-return-types-in-php7#33609210)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nullable return types in PHP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608821/nullable-return-types-in-php7)