# Getting parse error when i try to send reset password link in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I am using `Laravel 5.4`. I am getting error when i try to request `password reset link`.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableErrorPOST
>   /password/email Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE)

File that error is pointing to is this ( at line `'return $next($request)'`

> > app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:24App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::handle

```
 namespace App\Http\Middleware;
 use Closure; 
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class RedirectIfAuthenticated {
 /**
  * Handle an incoming request.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  \Closure  $next
  * @param  string|null  $guard
  * @return mixed
  */
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
 {
     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
         return redirect('/');
     }

     return $next($request);
 } 
}
```

I debugged further into code and found out that this function is prolly causing issue.
FILE NAME:Symfony\Component\CssSelector\XPath\Extension\AttributeMatchingExtension

```
public function translateExists(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
{
    return $xpath->addCondition($attribute);
}
```

Comment: what is $next? and $request. `$next seems a variable` but you are treating as a function. Can you please tell

Comment: show us your email view of reset password and controller code

Comment: Its laravel default middleware for redirecting a request if the user is not guest.

Comment: It's missing `extends Middleware`.

Comment: @Sohel0415, i am using default laravel user login and password reset mechanism , i tried debugging code and the request gets redirected from middleware. (i tried debugging in this method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset )

Comment: PS: i am getting error on live server, i tried on local environment and it is working.  i tried comparing both files and they are same as well.

Comment: What version of `PHP` on your server and your local?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra , my local environment has PHP 7.1.7 and my live server has PHP  7.0.24. i updated my composer yesterday and vendor folder got updated (including symfony). PS: check my post i updated some info

Comment: I try looking at packagist, the supported version of the `symfony/css-selector` based on your server `PHP` version is `symfony/css-selector:3.4.*` https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/css-selector#v3.4.3. And looking at the source code, https://github.com/symfony/css-selector/blob/3.4/XPath/Extension/AttributeMatchingExtension.php, I'm pretty sure that what you get is the `symfony/css-selector:4.*` version. `?string` syntax seems not supported until `PHP 7.1`. Still try to find the reference. The easy way solution for you is upgrade the PHP version on your server.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra , thank you and all that helped, i'll try to upgrade PHP version and see what happens.

Comment: Ahh.. Finally found it: It's called `Nullable types`: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608821/nullable-return-types-in-php7#answer-33609210

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with `php 7.0.23` and Laravel 5.5 using the php `mail()` function:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) at [...]/vendor/symfony/css-selector/XPath/Extension/AttributeMatchingExtension.php:46`

The problem was solved by upgrading to version `php 7.1`. (it also works with `php 7.2`)

Comment: this has also fixed the my problem, upgrading `php7.0` to `php7.1.*`