# What is the correct type hint for an array of entities?

Tags: php, symfony, type-hinting

I have a an array in my symfony controller like this:

```
$schedules = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Hours')->findBy(
    array(
        'id' => $request->get('ids'),
    ),
        array(
            'start' => 'ASC',
            'status' => 'ASC'
        )
    );
```

I now take this to a function like this:

```
$result = $this->get('app.wiki')->generateInvoice($schedules, $request->get('invoice'));`
```

and the function expects parameters like this:

```
function generateInvoice(Hours $schedules, $invoiceNo)
{

    foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So obviously it the function expects a single entity of `Hours` but gets an array of it. How can I change the parameters to expect an array of `Hours` e.g. `function generateInvoice(Hours[] $schedules, $invoiceNo)` or similar.

`function generateInvoice(Array $schedules, $invoiceNo)` works ofc, but not exactly what I want.

Comment: There's no such typehint as `array of objects`

Comment: I voted to close this, 
it has already been well answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273367/type-hinting-in-php-7-array-of-objects

Comment: yes, couldn't find it so thanks!